# Checking my Intel collection progress

Tags: ps3, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

Where can I find the number of Intel items I have found for each level? I am sure I seen something at one point but I may be getting confused. Either way I cannot find them now.

If I remember correctly from past games, this could be found on the mission select screen but it is not there this time.

Some how, on my first play through I didn't manage to find any! Perhaps I was expected big orange boxes. Now I am replaying on veteran and have decided to keep a look out. So far I have found 3 on the first level and and working through the second at the moment (I think I have 2 so far)

It is not so much a problem at the moment but I would like to see which ones I missed upon completion so I can go back and find them

Thanks

Comment: Kind of tangential to the question, but this YouTube video contains all the intel locations, if you get stuck.  There are bookmarks in the description that jump you to each one, in case you just want to see a single location: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ag86fBhw9og&feature=player_embedded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember rightly it was World at War that had them on the mission select screen, and with the Modern Warfare games the only place you could see how many you had collected was by pausing during a mission

Comment: You are correct, they are on the pause screen (not ideal). I don't pause very often so perhaps this is why I forget where I seen it. Black Ops also had them on the mission select.

Answer (score 2):

Just go to your pause menu and it is at the bottom right hand corner